# Display div's as grid

Tags: html, css

I'd like to form a square matrix using DIV's.

Div's need to be tangent and show like an Excel spreadsheet, 10 by 10 small square's.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: What did you tried? show some code? use bootstrap http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp or use table

Comment: Why divs? If you have tabular data then use a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
.main-div {
    width: 900px;
}
.small-div {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc; float:left;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="main-div">
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>
  <div class="small-div"></div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution would be to set the size of the squares as well as the container to a fixed size.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="square"></div>
   <div class="square"></div>
   ...
</div>
```

Let´s say your squares should be 20x20 pixels. Then to achieve a 10x10 Grid, the container needs to be 200x200 pixels.

Adding a border would break that. So also set the box-sizing to include the border to the 20px.

```
.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.square {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

The standard html flow should do the rest.

An other approach is to use a table. But it´s a little complicated to make the cells being squares.